# Anime with humans fighting aliens and telepathy involved

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime

Probably 70's or 80's. Story is that a girl discovers a golden halo (if I remember correctly it was gold and went around the head more or less like a crown) which gives her telekinetic powers.

But she starts to see green aliens which soon attack her. A group of other people soon appear who fight these aliens. Their leader is a woman. The aliens come out of a red pool. Their story is that ancient people shut down a ship of theirs and halos were spread.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to the anime titled [*Nayuta (1986)*](https://iroiro.neocities.org/Anime/nayuta.htm).

> ... This is a show about aliens secretly observing the Earth when one day a high school girl, named Nayuta, becomes an esper, discovers what they’re up to, and tries to put a stop to it. It’s an entertaining adventure that can get a bit convoluted toward the end when the story gives viewers its take on how the universe functions and humanity’s role within it. Nevertheless, there’s a good time to be had here.
>
> Things start off with Nayuta happening upon a boy and his mother walking down the street. The mother is in bad shape, so Nayuta gets her to a hospital. Not long after this, the woman and her son disappear and the hospital staff say Nayuta never brought anyone in. Confused, she goes home and before long the boy shows up and teleports into Nayuta’s room. Here she quickly realizes he’s an esper and is quite pleased by this because she always thought they weren’t real. With that, the boy is taken into the family, who are surprisingly nonchalant with the boy’s frequent acts of telepathy. Eventually, viewers learn that the tiara that he is wearing is what awoke these powers inside of him. A short while later, Nayuta gets a hold of the tiara and is eventually able to see green people when she is out and about town (the They Live connection). It doesn’t take too long before she’s swept away in a resistance movement to push back these aliens, but one thing leads to another and she winds up finding herself going to Pluto where everything is made clear and a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you explain why you believe this is the anime the OP is looking for?